# How should a list window and edit window scenario be structured in MVVM WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

At the momement, I have an Edit button on each row in the list window, which calls an `EditRow` command on the list view model. This instantiates an edit window, which takes care of it's own view model.

It's all good and well, but how do I propagate changes in the edit window back to the list? Do I expose an UpdateRow command that is called by the edit window, or something like that?

Then, how do I handle errors, and the OK or Cancel outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You use `ObservableCollection` and have objects within that collection implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so when you edit an object which is a member of that `ObservableCollection` in your edit window the changes are automagically visible in your list as well...

That will also take care of handling errors and Cancellations in your edit window because if you cancel an edit or handle an error in your edit window anything that you do to that object in your edit window will, again, propagate automagically back to the list because you're working on the same object from the same `ObservableCollection`.

If you intend on using threading when accessing an object contained in your `ObservableCollection` it is probably a good idea to use ObservableCollectionMt which can be found on codeproject.

Comment: What about something like a DB validation (or other) error? Do I just follow the pattern: an error view and it's viewmodel, and a command on the edit view model to announce and handle the error?

Comment: Usually, you'd send an error notification form your VM to your V and your view would handle displaying error in a user friendly way. Your VM would however handle the error returned by the DAL by reverting changes to your object which is a member of the OC so nothing else would be needed.

Comment: `IEditableObject` is a useful interface for objects which support editing with commit/rollback support.